# How to output value of array which is set by php class?

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop

I hope someone can help me with my problem. I'm still a beginner in PHP so sorry.
My code looks like this:

```
class Component
{
    public $title;

    // value if nothing gets set
    public function __construct($title = "Test") {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function setTitle($value)
    {
        $this->title = $value;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return "Title: ".$this->title;
    } 

    public function returnInfo()
    {
        $info = array(
        'Titel'         => $this->title,            
        );      

        return $info;
    }
```

So in the class "Component" the functions should set and get a specific value. If nothing is set for a.e. title it should get the value "Test". With returnInfo() the informations like title should get returned.

My other class (where someone can add the informations like title) looks like this:

```
abstract class ComponentInfo extends Component
{
    protected function getComponentInfo ()
    {
        $button1 = new Component;
        $button1->setTitle("Button-Standard");

        // should return all infos for button1
        $button1Info = $button1->returnInfo();

        foreach ($button1Info as $info)
        {
            echo ($info);
        }
    }
}
```

So it should work like this: in a other class named ComponentInfo a user can add a component like a button. Then the user can set informations like the title. And after that the information should get saved in an array and now I want to display all informations like this:

**Title: Button-Standard**

How can it work? And where is the mistake in my code?

It would be helpful to get a working code where the user can make as much ComponentInfo classes he want and where he can add different components with information that can be saved into an array.

And at the end it should get outputed as text on a main page.

Comment: Do you mean you want something like `foreach ($button1Info as $label => $info)` and then `echo $label.":".$info;`?

Comment: yes but then it should output the text "Button-Standard" which I've set with setTitle. So it still not output anything

Answer (score -1):

You can't instantiate an abstract class. You need to remove the `abstract` keyword from the `ComponentInfo` class.

**UPDATE** given the info in your comment, I'd go this

`Component.php`

```php
abstract class Component
{
    private $key;
    private $title;

    public function __construct($key, $title) {
        $this->setKey($key);
        $this->setTitle($title);
    }

    public function setKey($key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->key;
    } 

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getKey().': '.$this->getTitle();
    }

}
```

`ComponentInfo.php`

```php
class ComponentInfo extends Component
{
    public function __construct($key='Info', $title='example title')
    {
        parent::__construct($key, $title);
    }
}
```

And then use it in your code
`somefile.php`

```php
$components = [];
$components []= new ComponentInfo();
$components []= new ComponentInfo('Different Key', 'Other info');
$components []= new ComponentNavigation('longitude', 'latidude'); //create another class like ComponentInfo

[... later you want to print this info in a list for example]

echo '<ul>';
foreach($components as $components) {
    echo '<li>'.$component.'</li>'; //the __toString() method should get called automatically
}
echo '</ul>';
```

This should work, however, having different components with no other specificities than a different title and key is pointless. Instead, you could simply have different `Component`s with a different key and title.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My idea was that I create more than one ComponentInfo classes. At example if I want to add a component with the name "form" I want to create a new ComponentInfo class where I can set the title or other values. When I want to create a new component like "navigation" I want to build also a ComponentInfo class where a.e. the title is navigation. And all the informations of the different components should get saved into an array. The information of the array should get displayed on a main page like "Title: Navigation, Description: ..." (if I add more attributes like title)

Comment: Thank you really much for your fast answer. Is there a way to output the text like this? Title: Button [new line] Description: a specific Button [new line] ... so that there are everytime for a new item a new line. Now it is like this: Title: button Description: a button

Comment: It depends where you're displaying it. What I show you will create a list in a browser, with bulletpoints. Otherwise you can remove the `echo '<ul>'` and `echo '</ul>'` and remove the `<li>` tags, and replace by `echo $component.PHP_EOL` or `echo $component.'<br/>`